# How can I write to char in structure with sprintf

Tags: c

I wrote this program for school but even if it finishes, dev-cpp gives me a SIGSEGV error at the end.
By searching on google i found that my problem probably comes from everything that is bound to my chars in my structures.
I am trying to write on my char nom[10] and char nom_team[10] with sprintf.
I do this because I want to ad a number to the default "player" name like so :
player 1, player 2,...

I don't know exactly where I am trying to write on memory that I don't own.
I don't know any other way to achieve the player 1, player 2,... thing either.

Thank you for the help.

EDIT (full code & edit following Michael Walz comment)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef struct player player; //shortened Perso type
typedef struct team Team; //shortened Team type

struct player //perso structure
{
    char name[10]; //player name
    int HP; //healt points
    int ATK; //attack points
    int DEF; //defense points
};

struct team //team structure
{
    char name_team[10]; //team name
    player player[5]; //players in the team
    int nbrP; //number of players left
};

void init_player (player*); //player initialisation
void fight (player*,player*); //damage calculation
int HPP (player*,player*); //players duel simulation
void init_team (Team*); //team initialisation
char* TvT (Team*,Team*); //team combat simulation

main() //main
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int i;
    char* wint; //winning team name string
    Team t[2]; //the 2 teams
    for (i=1;i<3;i++)
    {
        init_team (&t[i]); //teams initialisation
    }
    //changing team names
    sprintf(t[1].name_team,"%s","Orange");
    sprintf(t[2].name_team,"%s","Verte");
    //changing players names
    sprintf(t[1].player[0].name,"%s","Gerald");
    sprintf(t[1].player[1].name,"%s","Ilda");
    sprintf(t[1].player[2].name,"%s","Falion");
    sprintf(t[1].player[3].name,"%s","Thor");
    sprintf(t[1].player[4].name,"%s","Ralof");
    sprintf(t[2].player[0].name,"%s","Gandalf");
    sprintf(t[2].player[1].name,"%s","Jaena");
    sprintf(t[2].player[2].name,"%s","Philip");
    sprintf(t[2].player[3].name,"%s","Astrid");
    sprintf(t[2].player[4].name,"%s","Ponchaut");
    wint = TvT (&t[1],&t[2]); //wint is the result of the combat between the two teams  
    printf("%s\n",wint);
}

void init_player (player* p) //player initialisation
{
    static int i=1; //static variable for player number
    sprintf(p->name,"player %d",i); //applying player name
    p->HP = 100 + rand()%10; //giving HP
    p->ATK = 10 + rand()%10; //giving ATK
    p->DEF = 5 + rand()%5; //giving DEF
    printf("name : %s\n",p->name);
    printf("HP : %d\n",p->HP);
    printf("ATK : %d\n",p->ATK);
    printf("DEF : %d\n",p->DEF);
    printf("\n");
    //showing player stats
    i++; //next player number
}

void fight (player *p1,player *p2) //damage calculation
{
    int DAM;
    DAM = p1->ATK - p2->DEF; //simple damage calculation
    printf("DAM : %d\n",DAM); //showing damage done
    p2->HP = p2->HP - DAM; //applying damage
}

int HPP (player *p1,player *p2) //players duel simulation
{
    int turnp; //turns of the duel
    for (turnp=1;p1->HP>0 && p2->HP>0;turnp++) //continues while players are alive
    {
        printf("HP p1 : %d\n",p1->HP); //showing hp before combat
        printf("HP p2 : %d\n",p2->HP);
        if(turnp%2 != 0) fight (p1,p2); //p1 always begin
        else fight (p2,p1); //then it's p2's turn to attack
    }
    if (p1->HP<=0) return 2; //p2 is the winner if p1 dies
    else return 1; //p1 is the winner is p2 dies
}

void init_team (Team* t) //team initialisation
{
    int i;
    static int k=1; //static variable for team number
    sprintf(t->name_team,"team %d",k); //applying team name
    t->nbrP = 5; //defining number of players left in team at the start
    for (i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        init_player(&t->player[i]); //initializing players in team
    }
    k++; //next team number
}

char* TvT (Team* t1, Team* t2) //team combat simulation
{
    int turnt,winp; //team combat turns and duel winner variables
    int i=0,j=0;
    for (turnt=1;t1->nbrP>0 && t2->nbrP>0;turnt++) //continues while the teams have at least one player left alive
    {
        printf("%s de la team %s contre %s de la team %s\n",t1->player[i].name,t1->name_team,t2->player[j].name,t2->name_team);
        //introduction message to next duel
        winp =  HPP (&t1->player[i],&t2->player[j]); //simulating duel, the result is stored in winp
        if (winp == 1)
        {
            (t2->nbrP)--; //if player in team 2 dies we decrement the number of players left in that team
            j++; //we order the next player in the team 2 to duel
        }
        else
        {
            (t1->nbrP)--; ///if player in team 1 dies we decrement the number of players left in that team
            i++; //we order the next player in the team 1 to duel
        }
    }
    if(t1->nbrP<=0) return t2->name_team; //if team 1 loses we return team 2's name
    else return t1->name_team; //if team 2 loses we return team 1's name
}
```

NOTE : When I put

```
char name[100]
```

and

```
char name_team[100]
```

I get only this

```
name : player 1
HP : 103
ATK : 19
DEF : 9

name : player 2
HP : 100
ATK : 12
DEF : 6

name : player 3
HP : 107
ATK : 12
DEF : 8

name : player 4
HP : 101
ATK : 19
DEF : 6

name : player 5
HP : 108
ATK : 17
DEF : 8


--------------------------------
Process exited after 2.507 seconds with return value 3221225477
Appuyez sur une touche pour continuer...
```

The result I want is this (except that when t2 wins is writen "@■b" at the the bottom instea of "Verte" :

```
name : player 1
HP : 109
ATK : 14
DEF : 9

name : player 2
HP : 106
ATK : 12
DEF : 8

name : player 3
HP : 106
ATK : 17
DEF : 8

name : player 4
HP : 100
ATK : 11
DEF : 8

name : player 5
HP : 103
ATK : 12
DEF : 9

name : player 6
HP : 106
ATK : 12
DEF : 6

name : player 7
HP : 105
ATK : 13
DEF : 7

name : player 8
HP : 107
ATK : 19
DEF : 7

name : player 9
HP : 100
ATK : 16
DEF : 8

name : player 10
HP : 105
ATK : 11
DEF : 9

Gerald de la team Orange contre Gandalf de la team Verte
HP p1 : 109
HP p2 : 106
DAM : 8
HP p1 : 109
HP p2 : 98
DAM : 3
HP p1 : 106
HP p2 : 98
DAM : 8
HP p1 : 106
HP p2 : 90
DAM : 3
HP p1 : 103
HP p2 : 90
DAM : 8
HP p1 : 103
HP p2 : 82
DAM : 3
HP p1 : 100
HP p2 : 82
DAM : 8
HP p1 : 100
HP p2 : 74
DAM : 3
HP p1 : 97
HP p2 : 74
DAM : 8
HP p1 : 97
HP p2 : 66
DAM : 3
HP p1 : 94
HP p2 : 66
DAM : 8
HP p1 : 94
HP p2 : 58
DAM : 3
HP p1 : 91
HP p2 : 58
DAM : 8
HP p1 : 91
HP p2 : 50
DAM : 3
HP p1 : 88
HP p2 : 50
DAM : 8
HP p1 : 88
HP p2 : 42
DAM : 3
HP p1 : 85
HP p2 : 42
DAM : 8
HP p1 : 85
HP p2 : 34
DAM : 3
HP p1 : 82
HP p2 : 34
DAM : 8
HP p1 : 82
HP p2 : 26
DAM : 3
HP p1 : 79
HP p2 : 26
DAM : 8
HP p1 : 79
HP p2 : 18
DAM : 3
HP p1 : 76
HP p2 : 18
DAM : 8
HP p1 : 76
HP p2 : 10
DAM : 3
HP p1 : 73
HP p2 : 10
DAM : 8
HP p1 : 73
HP p2 : 2
DAM : 3
HP p1 : 70
HP p2 : 2
DAM : 8
Gerald de la team Orange contre Jaena de la team Verte
HP p1 : 70
HP p2 : 105
DAM : 7
HP p1 : 70
HP p2 : 98
DAM : 4
HP p1 : 66
HP p2 : 98
DAM : 7
HP p1 : 66
HP p2 : 91
DAM : 4
HP p1 : 62
HP p2 : 91
DAM : 7
HP p1 : 62
HP p2 : 84
DAM : 4
HP p1 : 58
HP p2 : 84
DAM : 7
HP p1 : 58
HP p2 : 77
DAM : 4
HP p1 : 54
HP p2 : 77
DAM : 7
HP p1 : 54
HP p2 : 70
DAM : 4
HP p1 : 50
HP p2 : 70
DAM : 7
HP p1 : 50
HP p2 : 63
DAM : 4
HP p1 : 46
HP p2 : 63
DAM : 7
HP p1 : 46
HP p2 : 56
DAM : 4
HP p1 : 42
HP p2 : 56
DAM : 7
HP p1 : 42
HP p2 : 49
DAM : 4
HP p1 : 38
HP p2 : 49
DAM : 7
HP p1 : 38
HP p2 : 42
DAM : 4
HP p1 : 34
HP p2 : 42
DAM : 7
HP p1 : 34
HP p2 : 35
DAM : 4
HP p1 : 30
HP p2 : 35
DAM : 7
HP p1 : 30
HP p2 : 28
DAM : 4
HP p1 : 26
HP p2 : 28
DAM : 7
HP p1 : 26
HP p2 : 21
DAM : 4
HP p1 : 22
HP p2 : 21
DAM : 7
HP p1 : 22
HP p2 : 14
DAM : 4
HP p1 : 18
HP p2 : 14
DAM : 7
HP p1 : 18
HP p2 : 7
DAM : 4
HP p1 : 14
HP p2 : 7
DAM : 7
Gerald de la team Orange contre Philip de la team Verte
HP p1 : 14
HP p2 : 107
DAM : 7
HP p1 : 14
HP p2 : 100
DAM : 10
HP p1 : 4
HP p2 : 100
DAM : 7
HP p1 : 4
HP p2 : 93
DAM : 10
Ilda de la team Orange contre Philip de la team Verte
HP p1 : 106
HP p2 : 93
DAM : 5
HP p1 : 106
HP p2 : 88
DAM : 11
HP p1 : 95
HP p2 : 88
DAM : 5
HP p1 : 95
HP p2 : 83
DAM : 11
HP p1 : 84
HP p2 : 83
DAM : 5
HP p1 : 84
HP p2 : 78
DAM : 11
HP p1 : 73
HP p2 : 78
DAM : 5
HP p1 : 73
HP p2 : 73
DAM : 11
HP p1 : 62
HP p2 : 73
DAM : 5
HP p1 : 62
HP p2 : 68
DAM : 11
HP p1 : 51
HP p2 : 68
DAM : 5
HP p1 : 51
HP p2 : 63
DAM : 11
HP p1 : 40
HP p2 : 63
DAM : 5
HP p1 : 40
HP p2 : 58
DAM : 11
HP p1 : 29
HP p2 : 58
DAM : 5
HP p1 : 29
HP p2 : 53
DAM : 11
HP p1 : 18
HP p2 : 53
DAM : 5
HP p1 : 18
HP p2 : 48
DAM : 11
HP p1 : 7
HP p2 : 48
DAM : 5
HP p1 : 7
HP p2 : 43
DAM : 11
Falion de la team Orange contre Philip de la team Verte
HP p1 : 106
HP p2 : 43
DAM : 10
HP p1 : 106
HP p2 : 33
DAM : 11
HP p1 : 95
HP p2 : 33
DAM : 10
HP p1 : 95
HP p2 : 23
DAM : 11
HP p1 : 84
HP p2 : 23
DAM : 10
HP p1 : 84
HP p2 : 13
DAM : 11
HP p1 : 73
HP p2 : 13
DAM : 10
HP p1 : 73
HP p2 : 3
DAM : 11
HP p1 : 62
HP p2 : 3
DAM : 10
Falion de la team Orange contre Astrid de la team Verte
HP p1 : 62
HP p2 : 100
DAM : 9
HP p1 : 62
HP p2 : 91
DAM : 8
HP p1 : 54
HP p2 : 91
DAM : 9
HP p1 : 54
HP p2 : 82
DAM : 8
HP p1 : 46
HP p2 : 82
DAM : 9
HP p1 : 46
HP p2 : 73
DAM : 8
HP p1 : 38
HP p2 : 73
DAM : 9
HP p1 : 38
HP p2 : 64
DAM : 8
HP p1 : 30
HP p2 : 64
DAM : 9
HP p1 : 30
HP p2 : 55
DAM : 8
HP p1 : 22
HP p2 : 55
DAM : 9
HP p1 : 22
HP p2 : 46
DAM : 8
HP p1 : 14
HP p2 : 46
DAM : 9
HP p1 : 14
HP p2 : 37
DAM : 8
HP p1 : 6
HP p2 : 37
DAM : 9
HP p1 : 6
HP p2 : 28
DAM : 8
Thor de la team Orange contre Astrid de la team Verte
HP p1 : 100
HP p2 : 28
DAM : 3
HP p1 : 100
HP p2 : 25
DAM : 8
HP p1 : 92
HP p2 : 25
DAM : 3
HP p1 : 92
HP p2 : 22
DAM : 8
HP p1 : 84
HP p2 : 22
DAM : 3
HP p1 : 84
HP p2 : 19
DAM : 8
HP p1 : 76
HP p2 : 19
DAM : 3
HP p1 : 76
HP p2 : 16
DAM : 8
HP p1 : 68
HP p2 : 16
DAM : 3
HP p1 : 68
HP p2 : 13
DAM : 8
HP p1 : 60
HP p2 : 13
DAM : 3
HP p1 : 60
HP p2 : 10
DAM : 8
HP p1 : 52
HP p2 : 10
DAM : 3
HP p1 : 52
HP p2 : 7
DAM : 8
HP p1 : 44
HP p2 : 7
DAM : 3
HP p1 : 44
HP p2 : 4
DAM : 8
HP p1 : 36
HP p2 : 4
DAM : 3
HP p1 : 36
HP p2 : 1
DAM : 8
HP p1 : 28
HP p2 : 1
DAM : 3
Thor de la team Orange contre Ponchaut de la team Verte
HP p1 : 28
HP p2 : 105
DAM : 2
HP p1 : 28
HP p2 : 103
DAM : 3
HP p1 : 25
HP p2 : 103
DAM : 2
HP p1 : 25
HP p2 : 101
DAM : 3
HP p1 : 22
HP p2 : 101
DAM : 2
HP p1 : 22
HP p2 : 99
DAM : 3
HP p1 : 19
HP p2 : 99
DAM : 2
HP p1 : 19
HP p2 : 97
DAM : 3
HP p1 : 16
HP p2 : 97
DAM : 2
HP p1 : 16
HP p2 : 95
DAM : 3
HP p1 : 13
HP p2 : 95
DAM : 2
HP p1 : 13
HP p2 : 93
DAM : 3
HP p1 : 10
HP p2 : 93
DAM : 2
HP p1 : 10
HP p2 : 91
DAM : 3
HP p1 : 7
HP p2 : 91
DAM : 2
HP p1 : 7
HP p2 : 89
DAM : 3
HP p1 : 4
HP p2 : 89
DAM : 2
HP p1 : 4
HP p2 : 87
DAM : 3
HP p1 : 1
HP p2 : 87
DAM : 2
HP p1 : 1
HP p2 : 85
DAM : 3
Ralof de la team Orange contre Ponchaut de la team Verte
HP p1 : 103
HP p2 : 85
DAM : 3
HP p1 : 103
HP p2 : 82
DAM : 2
HP p1 : 101
HP p2 : 82
DAM : 3
HP p1 : 101
HP p2 : 79
DAM : 2
HP p1 : 99
HP p2 : 79
DAM : 3
HP p1 : 99
HP p2 : 76
DAM : 2
HP p1 : 97
HP p2 : 76
DAM : 3
HP p1 : 97
HP p2 : 73
DAM : 2
HP p1 : 95
HP p2 : 73
DAM : 3
HP p1 : 95
HP p2 : 70
DAM : 2
HP p1 : 93
HP p2 : 70
DAM : 3
HP p1 : 93
HP p2 : 67
DAM : 2
HP p1 : 91
HP p2 : 67
DAM : 3
HP p1 : 91
HP p2 : 64
DAM : 2
HP p1 : 89
HP p2 : 64
DAM : 3
HP p1 : 89
HP p2 : 61
DAM : 2
HP p1 : 87
HP p2 : 61
DAM : 3
HP p1 : 87
HP p2 : 58
DAM : 2
HP p1 : 85
HP p2 : 58
DAM : 3
HP p1 : 85
HP p2 : 55
DAM : 2
HP p1 : 83
HP p2 : 55
DAM : 3
HP p1 : 83
HP p2 : 52
DAM : 2
HP p1 : 81
HP p2 : 52
DAM : 3
HP p1 : 81
HP p2 : 49
DAM : 2
HP p1 : 79
HP p2 : 49
DAM : 3
HP p1 : 79
HP p2 : 46
DAM : 2
HP p1 : 77
HP p2 : 46
DAM : 3
HP p1 : 77
HP p2 : 43
DAM : 2
HP p1 : 75
HP p2 : 43
DAM : 3
HP p1 : 75
HP p2 : 40
DAM : 2
HP p1 : 73
HP p2 : 40
DAM : 3
HP p1 : 73
HP p2 : 37
DAM : 2
HP p1 : 71
HP p2 : 37
DAM : 3
HP p1 : 71
HP p2 : 34
DAM : 2
HP p1 : 69
HP p2 : 34
DAM : 3
HP p1 : 69
HP p2 : 31
DAM : 2
HP p1 : 67
HP p2 : 31
DAM : 3
HP p1 : 67
HP p2 : 28
DAM : 2
HP p1 : 65
HP p2 : 28
DAM : 3
HP p1 : 65
HP p2 : 25
DAM : 2
HP p1 : 63
HP p2 : 25
DAM : 3
HP p1 : 63
HP p2 : 22
DAM : 2
HP p1 : 61
HP p2 : 22
DAM : 3
HP p1 : 61
HP p2 : 19
DAM : 2
HP p1 : 59
HP p2 : 19
DAM : 3
HP p1 : 59
HP p2 : 16
DAM : 2
HP p1 : 57
HP p2 : 16
DAM : 3
HP p1 : 57
HP p2 : 13
DAM : 2
HP p1 : 55
HP p2 : 13
DAM : 3
HP p1 : 55
HP p2 : 10
DAM : 2
HP p1 : 53
HP p2 : 10
DAM : 3
HP p1 : 53
HP p2 : 7
DAM : 2
HP p1 : 51
HP p2 : 7
DAM : 3
HP p1 : 51
HP p2 : 4
DAM : 2
HP p1 : 49
HP p2 : 4
DAM : 3
HP p1 : 49
HP p2 : 1
DAM : 2
HP p1 : 47
HP p2 : 1
DAM : 3
Orange

--------------------------------
Process exited after 5.682 seconds with return value 3221225477
Appuyez sur une touche pour continuer...
```

In either case, when I just compile and run the program using dev-cpp, windows tells me it crashed after everything is done.
When I use the [debug with -g argument](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4I1KW.png)

I get SIGSEGV error at the end.

NOTE 2 : We didn't learn snprintf yet so I am not allowed to use this command; there are no actual inputs; and about the line that gives the SIGSEGV error, I don't know how to ask dev-cpp to say which line it is, the only method I've got is to turn blocks of code into commentary (obviously keeping  a compilable program) until the error disappears and I led me to this line :

```
sprintf(p->name,"player %d",i); //applying player name
```

Comment: post the full code.

Comment: In `init_Perso` does `i` ever go over 99? If it does, then your `sprintf(p->nom ...` will exceed the 10 bytes you allocated to `p->nom`. Without seeing where you are calling `init_Perso` it's hard to tell whether you might have a bug in that area.

Comment: This is a good time to look into using GDB and step through your program.

Comment: `char nom[10]` and `char nom_team[10];`: 10 is a bit short, try `[100]` instead of `[10]`. If the problem goes away, you know where to look.

Comment: ... and please show how you call `init_team`. The origin of your problem may be there.

Comment: Offtopic, please write comments in english (escpecially if you're going to post your code in an international forum).

Comment: Offtopic: `char nteam[] = "team"; sprintf(t->nom_team,"%s %d",nteam,k);` can be replaced by `sprintf(t->nom_team,"%s %d", "team", k);` or even simpler by `sprintf(t->nom_team, "team %d", k);`

Comment: which line is causing the seg fault event?

Comment: how are we to help you if we cannot reproduce the problem?  Please post code that 1) is short 2) cleanly compiles 3) still displays the problem  IT would be a good idea to also post the actual inputs, the expected outputs and the actual outputs

Comment: I will soon post a translated version of my code, sorry for this inconvenience. I didn't really know how to do it since it was my first post in this forum.

Comment: Try `snprintf(p->nom, p->nom, sizeof "%s %d",npl,i);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Team` array has 2 elements, but you are putting stuff into indexes 1 and 2.  Arrays in C are zero-based - the first element is `[0]`, so you want to use elements `[0]` and `[1]` instead:

```
Team t[2];
...
sprintf(t[0].name_team,"%s","Orange");
sprintf(t[1].name_team,"%s","Verte");
... 
// etc - change all t[1] references to t[0], and all t[2] references to t[1]
```

Also change your `for` loop to `for (i=0;i<2;i++)`.

When you write into index `[2]`, you are overwriting memory that doesn't belong to you and corrupting the stack.

Comment: Many thanks ! It's working perfectly now. Is there a way to mark this question as "solved" ?